# ¿Existe alguna manera de crear autoscroll a un listview?, en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Tengo un problema, realice un ejemplo de un chat que encontré en Internet, el ejemplo funciona muy bien solo que a la hora de probarlo mandaba mensajes y no se hacia autoscroll cada que mandaba mensajes, tenia que hacer scroll yo mismo para poder ver el mensaje nuevo recibido... Y en base a esto me surgió la duda si hay algún método de que se pueda hacer autoscroll a un listview? para que cada que reciba un mensaje me aparezca en pantalla y no tenga yo que subir el listview para poder ver el mensaje

aquí el link del tutorial que seguí para hacer el chat...

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase--cms-27397

Answer (score 1):

Amigos ya arregle mi problema fue sencillo solo tuve que poner estas tres lineas en el onCreate

```
    ListView listOfMessage = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_message);
    listOfMessage.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
    listOfMessage.setStackFromBottom(true);
```

Donde listOfMessage toma el valor de mi ListView llamado list_of_message...
y listo era todo con eso hay autoscroll cada que recibo un mensaje...